# Camel Splitter: Add individual headers based on body

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to split a message containing a map. According to my tutorial, I have to use a custom service to implement the actual splitting

```
public class CustomService {
  public List split(Map map) {
    return map.values();
  }
}

//route ...
.split().method(CustomService.class, "split")
   .choice()
   //...
.end()
```

So far, everything works fine. However, now I want to route the messages differently depending on some header value I would like to set in the `split(Map)` message. Is it possible to add different header values for each message during the split?

Answer (score 9):

You can only add headers in the split method if you return a `List<Message>` eg `org.apache.camel.Message` instances where you can adjust the headers.

Something a long the lines of (mind pseudo like code)

```
public class CustomService {
  public List split(Exchange exchange) {
    List list = new ArrayList();

    Map map = exchange.getIn().getBody(Map.class);
    for (Object value : map.values()) {
       // either copy or create a new DefaultMessage
       Message msg = new DefaultMessage();
       msg.setBody(value);
       // we want to copy the existing headers
       msg.setHeaders(exchange.getIn().getHeaders();
       // and then customize the headers
       msg.setHeader("foo", "bar");
       list.add(msg);
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: But, doesn't this lead to messages contain messages as payload? So the outer message does not contain the header values, so I can't use that for routing messages.

Comment: No if its an org.apache.camel.Message then its used as-is

Comment: @Claus Ibsen msg.setHeader("foo", mapKey );  results the same "foo" header for each msg...

Comment: Constructor for DefaultMessage seems to be depreciated now so one should probably use `Message msg = new DefaultMessage(exchange.getContext());` instead.

Answer (score 2):

@Claus, thanks- your solution (almost) worked. Only change was instead of

```
msg.setHeaders(exchange.getIn().getHeaders();
```

I had

```
msg.setHeaders(new HashMap<String, Object> (exchange.getIn().getHeaders()));
```

This way each message has its own header.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another solution because if you split and add camel headers in one method it's not that obvious for others that this happens in the same method.
Instead I would suggest, that you "convert" your map into custom POJO's which contain all information you need for splitting and routing.

So each entry in your map becomes an own custom POJO which you can collect in a list which is then splittable.

Here is an example of what I did in the (almost) same situation:

```
.log(INFO, log, "Some information in my route")
.process(mapToPOJOConverter) // An custom processor which does nothing more than converting the Map to your java.util.List of POJO's. Can also be a custom TypeConverter
.split(simple("${body}")).shareUnitOfWork().stopOnException() //Split the List so that in your splitted route you'll get each custom POJO
.to("direct:internAfterSplit")

from("direct:internAfterSplit").routeId(ROUTE_ALIAS_KUNDENARBEITSLISTE_INTERN) //Always use routeId for easy identifying where problems might be
  .log(INFO, log, "Start Route: ${routeId}")
  .bean(yourExchangeEnricher, "setHeadersIntoExchange")
  .log(INFO, log, "Message is rooted to: [your custom endpoint]")
  .to("[your custom endpoint which depends on the headers]")
```

With this way it's always obvious in the route where the headers are generated which are then used in the endpoint. 
I personally try to avoid `java.util.Map` when I implement Camel routes, as most times there is a better solution instead of `java.util.Map` like an own POJO.